# Вывести полученные списки в порядке возрастания по сумме абсолютных значений отдельных элементов

Tags: python

Дан список из 30 случайных целых и дробных чисел от -100 до +100.
Сформировать из списка 10 списков по 3 элемента.

```
N = [random.randint(-100, 100) for i in range(30)]
print(N)
nls=[]
for i in range(0,10):nls.append(N[3*i:3*i+3])
print(nls)
```

Как Вывести полученные списки в порядке возрастания по сумме абсолютных значений отдельных элементов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если я правильно понял задание - сделайте так:

```
nls.sort(key = lambda obj: sum(map(abs, obj)))
```

т.е. сортировка по сумме абсолютных значений списка

```
map(abs, obj)
```

получает список абсолютных значений

```
sum(map(abs, obj))
```

вычисляет сумму значений списка

Comment: с первого выводит - None, 
в остальных Unresolved reference 'obj'

Comment: @Bohdan, а как вы код именно написали то? у меня все замечательно сработало

Comment: @Bohdan первый сортирует исходный список, чтобы создать новый используйте `sorted(nls, key=lambda obj:...)`(вместо `...` должен быть код). Остальные не работают потому что это просто примеры, объясняющие код

Comment: @Danis я так и не понял какой код, я спросил как решить, а мне загадки дают

Comment: @Bohdan в своём коде между циклом `for` и `print(nls)` заснутьте код, который начинается с `nls.sort`